# How to get products similar to my current product using its category on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I wanted to get all my products from the category of my current post (I want to create a gallery of my similar products).
I get the category of my current post but I am blocked after.

more details : I have created a page template for my products and I would like on each of my "product" pages to display similar products. I would therefore like to display all the products that have the same category as my product.

Could you help me please?

```
global $post;
$postcat = get_the_category( $post->ID );
```

Comment: You can do it by using another loop in same page, and pass category id to that loop, it will fetch that category posts

Comment: @CBroe Hello,
I do not understand the interest of your comment. I obviously looked on the net before asking my question and I obviously saw the page that you quoted me in your comment.
If I ask the question, it's because I couldn't find the answer on google. Could you explain your approach to me?

Comment: @ShakeelAhmad, thank you, I'm going to try

Comment: If need help just ping me Thanks

Comment: @ShakeelAhmad, hello, I tried but it does not work, I am a beginner and I cannot make the right request...

Comment: Okey let me write the code for you

Comment: @lulu i add the code please try it

Comment: @ShakeelAhmad hello, I just saw your message. sorry for the late response. I wanted to thank you for helping me. I tested your code and, with a few modifications, it works. a big thank you for your help!

Comment: please accept the answer to close this question Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it the single page where you display the post. i am also excluding the same post, that user did not see duplication

```
$post_id = get_the_ID(); //this will get the post id
$category_object = get_the_category($post_id); //this will get categories
$category_name = $category_object[0]->name; //select category from here

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category_name' => $category_name,
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'post__not_in' => array($post_id)
);
$arr_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

/* Start the Loop */
while ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) :
    $arr_posts->the_post();

    the_title();
    
endwhile; // End of the loop.
```

This will help you i test it on my localmachine